# failed to lazily getting data - JUnit test

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing

I would like to add a Junit test to a code which is already used by customers. 
This test will cover a DAO class. This Junit Test used hibernate,Spring and hlsql for the virtual database.

Here the error I got :

> ERROR [main] LazyInitializationException.(19) | failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   com.projet.dao.model.scenario.CategoryEntity.resultDescList, no
>   session or session was closed –

I have already look extensively on Google for this issue. I found that by adding @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 to the entity "CategoryEntity" for the object resultDescList it fixes the issue. But this solution is not acceptable because I should not modify the code to fix the junit.

I added the @Transactional annotation too to the test. But the error is still there . What other alternatives do I have to fix this issue ?

Unit Test :

```
@Test
@Transactional
    public final void testGetCategoryById() throws Exception
    {
        final Integer id = 1;
        CategoryEntity category = categoryDAO.getCategoryById(id);
        Assert.assertNotNull(category);
        Assert.assertEquals(id, category.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals("junit.cat.test1", category.getKey());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, category.getOrder().intValue());

        List< ResultDescEntity > resultDescList = category.getResultDescList();
        Assert.assertTrue(resultDescList.size() == 1);

        UnitTestEntity unitTest = category.getUnitTest();
        Assert.assertNotNull(unitTest);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, unitTest.getId().intValue());
        Assert.assertEquals(true, category.getVisible());
    }
```

Extract of the CategoryEntity class :

```
Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(selectBeforeUpdate = false, dynamicInsert = false, dynamicUpdate = false, optimisticLock = OptimisticLockType.NONE)
public class CategoryEntity implements IGenericEntity
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CategorySequence")
    @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "CategorySequence", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "category_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNITTEST_ID")
    private UnitTestEntity unitTest;

    @Column(name = "KEY", length = 50)
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ORDER")
    private Integer order;

    @Column(name = "VISIBLE")
    private Integer visible;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @IndexColumn(name = "RESULT_ORDER", base = 1)
    private List<ResultDescEntity> resultDescList;
```

Regards

Comment: Before spending time on this test, I would ask the question, "What value are you getting from this test?" Is it an integration test? (Hint: It is if it accesses the database.) If so, maybe you should be executing it at a higher level; we found that writing integration tests mid-tier of our application to be unmaintainable. To unit test it, you would have to mock out the objects that this method uses, but those objects are probably not ones you designed. That means you wouldn't be getting any design feedback. You might get something from this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9FOchgTtLM.

Comment: Thanks for your commenents. I am using hsql as a virtual database. I would like to do junit tests in order to cover the code original. I would like to avoid mock.

Comment: If you're just looking for coverage, then my advice would be to write an integration test that hits the top level of the application, preferably actually sending a web request.